# creating a custom message type including an image

Tags: ros, image, message, camera

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm trying to define and use a custom message type. This message will include a few primitive data types as well as a sensor_msgs/Image.msg type for transferring the image. I have not managed to work out how to define this last element yet.

Do I need to update the package dependencies somehow? What type name would I use for this.

I'm assuming this is even possible, if not would I need to make a copy of what's in the sensor_msgs/Image.msg instead.

Thanks

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/228667/creating-a-custom-message-type-including-an-image/) by [PeteBlackerThe3rd](https://answers.ros.org/users/25185/peteblackerthe3rd/) on ROS Answers with karma: 9529 on 2016-03-10

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2016-03-10**:
Please add whatever you currently already have, how you configured your `CMakeLists.txt` and what errors you are getting. Composing custom messages out of others is a typical use case that should-just-work if you set things up correctly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Thanks for the reply gvhoorn. I've managed to get to the bottom of this one now. I couldn't find any description of the syntax of the type name for messages from external packages. Through trial and error I worked out I needed to write this:

```
sensor_msgs/Image <variable name>
```

Now everything is working properly!

---

Originally posted by [PeteBlackerThe3rd](https://answers.ros.org/users/25185/peteblackerthe3rd/) with karma: 9529 on 2016-03-11

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 4

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2016-03-11**:
That is actually documented: from [wiki/msg - Field Types](http://wiki.ros.org/msg#Field_Types):

> When embedding other Message descriptions, the type name may be relative (e.g. `Point32`) if it is in the same package; otherwise it must be the full Message type (e.g. `std_msgs/String`).

**Comment by [PeteBlackerThe3rd](https://answers.ros.org/users/25185/peteblackerthe3rd/) on 2016-03-11**:
You're right. Not sure how I missed that the first time around!